# while в php не читает все данные из таблицы

Tags: php

У меня есть код с помощью которого я пытаюсь прочитать данные из таблицы.

```
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $role = array($row["content"]);
}
return $role;
```

Но я получаю только последнюю строку из таблицы..
Как получить все данные?
`fetchAll` не работает, уже пробовал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `$role` - просто переменная, не массив. Надо к ней добавить квадратные скобки, чтобы в неё дописывались значения, а в начале объявить её как массив:

```
$role = [];
while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $role[] = array($row["content"]);
}
return $role;
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало) Хотя до этого пробовал ставить скобки но данные не получал, видимо что-то упустил, спасибо!